# Как сравнить String и Char?

Tags: java

Выдает ошибку Incompatible operand types String and char

```
for(index = 0; index < User.length(); index++) {
   char[] morsec = User.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < morsec.length;i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < word.length;j++){
        if(`word[j] == morsec[i]`) {
          answer = answer + morze[j] + " ";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word.charAt(i) == morsec[i]
```

или

```
word[j].equals(new String(new char[]{morsec[i]}));
```